# It's not entering in to the loop, although the element matched was present in the table

Tags: selenium-webdriver, equals-operator

```
String bknum=d.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='error-back']/a[@style]")).getText();

List<WebElement> cols=d.findElements(By.xpath("//tbody/tr/td[2][text()]"));
System.out.println("Coloumn was selected");

for(WebElement col:cols){
    if(col.equals(bknum)){
        System.out.println("Bookng exists");
        d.findElement(By.xpath("//tbody/tr/td[2][contains(text(),"+bknum+")]/following-sibling::*[7]/a[2]/img")).click();
    }
```

Comment: Please suggest me how to work on this...
correct if i'm wrong

Comment: List<WebElement> cols=d.findElements(By.xpath("//tbody/tr/td[2][text()]"));
 System.out.println("Coloumn was selected");
 
 //int colCount=cols.size();    //got the coloumn size
 
 for(WebElement col:cols){  
  if(col.equals(bknum)){
   System.out.println("Bookng exists");
   d.findElement(By.xpath("//tbody/tr/td[2][contains(text(),"+bknum+")]/following-sibling::*[7]/a[2]/img")).click();
  }
  
 }

Comment: I used List<WebElement> only vivek

Comment: You are comparing an webelement to a string? Use `col.getText().equals()`...

Comment: if(col.equals(bknum)), Here col is a web element, bknum is String...is this the wring way..?

Comment: Welcome Harry.. but do remember my second comment for ur future posts. :)

Comment: if(col.getText().equals(bknum))...didn't wworks

Comment: can u provide your stack trace or error u r getting or console op?

Comment: By.xpath("//tbody/tr/td[2][contains(text(),"+bknum+")]/following-sibling::*[7]/a[2]/img")

Comment: i mentioned +bknum+, is the above is the correct way to write xpath..

Comment: No thats not an issue. U can write xpath like that for dynamic searches. Can u provide the html snippet?